# How to start cursor at right side of textarea?

Tags: html, css

If this is the textarea `|                    |`

I want the input to display like this

`|                   firstword|
|        firstword secondword|`

instead of this

`|firstword                    |
|firstword secondword         |`

Comment: Have u tried: style="text-align: right"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stylesheet:

```
textarea {
    text-align: right;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9zbc2j8s/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `text-align: right` on your input. For example:

```
input {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Another option is to use `direction: rtl` on your input:

```
input {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0kr0zr2/)